# How to trim python datetime to nearest of a certain frequency?

Tags: python

I'm a bit stumped here.

Given a frequency in seconds, like 86400, and an unknown datetime, let's say '2018-02-12 17:30:24',

How can I get the next complete occurrence of said frequency? In this case - '2018-02-13 00:00:00'

I tried the following possible solutions:

```
freq = 86400
starttime = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('2018-02-12 17:30:24')
startseconds = time.mktime(starttime.timetuple())
deltaseconds = startseconds%freq
remainder = freq - deltaseconds
result = startseconds + remainder
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(result))
# is 2018-02-12 19:00
```

This is not the correct result
I tried finding the timezone offset:

```
timezone_offset = time.mktime(datetime.date.today().timetuple())%86400 #freq will not always be 1 day, may be 3 hours, 2 weeks...
result = startseconds + remainder + timezone_offset
#this is 2018-02-12 23:00:00
```

This is also not the correct result.

I tried using the timedelta type, and it does not produce results any better.

So... given that I know the desired frequency in seconds, how can I trim a given datetime to the next of that one frequency?

Comment: Look at datetime.timedelta

Comment: @MichaelRobellard datetime.timedelta works in exactly the same way. I'm making `freqdelta = datetime.timedelta(seconds = freq)`. Then, I'm making `startdelta= datetime.timedelta(seconds = startseconds)`, and I'm taking `rem = startdelta%freqdelta`, then `finaldelta=startdelta+(freqdelta-rem)`, and finally `print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(finaldelta.total_seconds())` still getting the same 19:00, even though the final delta is exactly 17575 days and 0 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it with accounting for the time zone, but you forgot to account for daylight saving. To fix this, when you compute `timezone_offset` you want to use `starttime.date()` instead of `datetime.date.today()` because one of those dates may be in daylight saving while the other is not. The full code is then:

```
import datetime
import time

freq = 86400
starttime = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('2018-02-12 17:30:24')
startseconds = time.mktime(starttime.timetuple())
deltaseconds = startseconds % freq
remainder = freq - deltaseconds
timezone_offset = time.mktime(starttime.date().timetuple()) % freq
result = startseconds + remainder + timezone_offset
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(result))
```